# How to disable click on react-router-dom <Link> on condition

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

In my React app I have this line wherein I have to restrict clicking on the Link in case id is less than 1. How can I do this?

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to={`/edit/${id - 1}`}>Prev</Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing some key points, but I am assuming that `id` is a route parameter.

There are two ways to do this. Either, add a custom `onClick` handler that prevents clicking, or create a CSS class that has the rule `pointer-events: none;` and apply that to the `<Link />`. You can use the two together.

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const myLink = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <Link to={`/edit/${id - 1}`} onClick={id - 1 < 0 && this.handleClick}>Prev</Link>
  );

};
```

Reference this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1082#issuecomment-160348163) for more information.